# count character until ',' in sqldf in R

Tags: r, sqldf

I have a text with comma and I need count of number characters until comma, because i want select the interval before comma.

Example:
text: "12345, Supply"
I want select just "12345".
Is it possible?

tks!

Comment: Can you show the string correctly  Is it `"12345"` or `"12345, Supply"`

Comment: Hi akrun, it's "12345, Supply".

Answer (score 1):

With `sqldf`, one possibility is this

```
df <- data.frame(text = rep("12345, Supply", 2))

           text
1 12345, Supply
2 12345, Supply

sqldf("select substr(text, 1, instr(text, ',') - 1) as text from df")

   text
1 12345
2 12345
```

Comment: Sorry, it don't work.
Look my base:
DocNum Code Date Dep PK Amount Text
57434 5 26/09/2016 1280 D 112084,53 "10-1","Supply","text"

I need extract only the number before "," of field Text

Comment: You need to post some sample data then / what doesn't work

Comment: It does answer the question asked. Please fix your question if you did not ask what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub` to match the `,` followed by one or more spaces and other characters and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
sub(",\\s+.*", "", "12345, Supply")
#[1] "12345"
```

Or capture as a group and replace with the backreference

```
sub("^([^,]+),.*", "\\1", "12345, Supply")
#[1] "12345"
```

Comment: Sorry, it don't work.
Look my base:
DocNum  Code Date Dep        PK Amount         Text
57434  5    26/09/2016 1280 D 112084,53 "10-1","Supply","text"

I need extract only the number before "," of field Text